# Orientability of surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

How to prove that a surface is orientable? Is it true that the union of two orientable surfaces is orientable? How to prove that? For example, is the union of the hemisphere 
$$z = \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}$$ 
with the disk 
$$x^2 + y^2 \le 1$$ 
orientable?

Comment: So what is your definition of orientation?

Comment: I can't answer your question. The only notion of orientability of surfaces that I have is that seen in multivariable calculus.

Comment: The problem is that the union of the above two surfaces is not smooth. So I guess you need another definition?

Comment: Mobius strip is union of two pieces of orientable surfaces. However Mobius strip is not orientable.

Comment: Can you share with us your definition of orientability? I can think of at least one notion of orientability applicable to that space, but I don't know if it would be helpful to you.

Comment: Everything that I know is what I have seen in a multivariable calculus course. I didn't even know that there is more than one definition of orientability. But any answer you give will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As John Ma correctly points out, your space is not smooth along the intersection of the hemisphere and the disk, hence the smooth notion of orientation does not make sense. However, there is a [topological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability#Homology_and_the_orientability_of_general_manifolds) notion of orientability, using homology, which applies to your space.

It might be intuitively acceptable to you to think of "[smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function)" your space along that intersection; you could think of your space as the limit of arbitrarily smaller smoothings, and on any of these smooth approximations the standard smooth notion would apply.

In summary: rigorously your space is not smoothly orientable, but there are appropriate mild generalizations (which are often of practical use) under which your space is orientable.

Comment: In the Calculus book by Stewart he gives this definition : "If it is possible to choose a unit normal vector n at every such point (x, y, z) so that n varies continuously over S, then S is called an oriented surface and the given choice of n provides S with an orientation." Does this fit with what you said ?

Comment: For ease, consider the cross section of your surface in the $xz$-plane. Can you assign a unit normal vector at the point $(1,0,0)$, and points near it, so that $n$ varies continuously?

Answer (score 1):

One can do without smoothing: An orientation of the hemisphere $H$ induces an orientation (i.e., a sense of direction) of the boundary circle $\partial H$, say counterclockwise when seen from above. Similarly for the disk $D$. The question is whether you can orient the disk in such a way that the induced orientation of the boundary circle $\partial D$ is now clockwise, when seen from above. Of course you can do that. In this way the union of the two pieces of surface becomes a *closed oriented $2$-chain*, whereby "closed" refers to the circumstance that the two boundary circles now annihilate each other.